# Slicknav and delegated click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, slicknav

I'm rather new to coding and my understanding is limited. 
But I'm using Slicknav for mobile screen sizes, however according to the author of the plug in.

"SlickNav menu items are created Dynamically" so I need to use delegated click events or attach event handlers after SlickNav is created. 
[My SlickNav post](https://github.com/ComputerWolf/SlickNav/issues/138)

I need some help with this. According to [This](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), I tried making a delegated events.

Here is the original code which is a " direct" event handler (I think)

```
menuitem.eq(0).on('click', function(){
status = 1;
clearBox();
statusCheck();

});
```

BTW all my code is trying to do is 1. Clear out a Container which is a display window for content. And 2. Append the correct content to that window based on the menu item that is clicked.

Here is my attempt at a delegated event:

```
$('#navMenu').on('click',menuitem.eq(0), function(){
status = 1;
clearBox();
statusCheck();

});
```

Also tried replacing .on() with .delegate(),  no dice.

For completeness ill including the functions that the cick events are calling

```
function clearBox(){
$("#display_box").children().fadeOut(1000).appendTo(".holding");


};

function statusCheck(){
    if (status == 1){

    displaycontent.eq(0).fadeIn(1000).appendTo("#display_box");
    displaycontent.eq(0).removeClass("hide");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
    } else{}

    if (status == 2){

    displaycontent.eq(25).fadeIn(1000).appendTo("#display_box");
    displaycontent.eq(25).removeClass("hide");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
    } else{}  
    // Etc Etc Etc
```

Edit: Provided HTML for the Menu

```
<div class ="menu_wrap"> 
<nav id = "navMenu">
<ul class ="clearfix menu">
 <li>General
    <ul class="subMenu1">
        <li class ="menu_item">Introduction</li>
        <li class ="menu_item"> What you need</li>
        <li class ="menu_item">House Rules</li>
        <li class ="menu_item">Running the Game</li>
        <li class ="menu_item">Survival</li>
        <li class ="menu_item">Encounters</li>

    </ul>
   </li>
    <li>The World 
        <ul class ="subMenu1">
            <li class ="menu_item">Nol</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Wol</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Sol</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Eol</li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="index_maps.html">Locations and Maps</a></li>
<li>Races and Cultures
    <ul class ="subMenu1">
            <li> <a class="allow_default" href="index_npcs.html"   target="blank">NPC Creatures</a></li>
            <li class ="menu_item"> Voran Kingdom</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Doval Empire</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Salatai Sultanate</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Gamoran Republic</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Elandel</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Kingdom of Night</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Halflings</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Aiur' Dun</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Half-Elves</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Half-Orcs</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">Dryads</li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li> Organizations
    <ul class ="subMenu1">
            <li class="menu_item">Information</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Green Wardens</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Temple of Light</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Black Hand</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Stone Priests</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Golden Company</li>
            <li class ="menu_item">The Dread Guards</li>
            </ul>

</li>

<li class ="menu_item">Character Creation
    <ul class ="subMenu1">
        <li class ="menu_item"> <a class="allow_default"      href="index_personality_test.html" target="blank">Creation Test</a></li>
    </ul>   
</li>


</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: When using `.on()` for delegated event handling, the second parameter to `.on()` should be a selector, not a JQuery object (or a DOM element). That is, it should be a string.

Comment: So then `$('#navMenu').on(menuitem.eq(0),'click',  function(){
status = 1;
clearBox();
statusCheck();

});`

Would this work ?

Comment: No, `'click'` should be the first parameter, but for the second parameter, instead of using `menuitem.eq(0)`, you need to use a selector that identifies the menu item element or elements for which you want to handle the click event.

Comment: Well I cant use a class because they all have the same class.... 
and I cant use an ID because SLicknav works by cloning the menu and HTML doesn't allow two of the same ID's ... 

So I suppose I could use  a selector that contains the string "XXXXXX" and just change it for each list item?  

But again Im very new, refresh my memory how would I do that in this case?

Comment: Can you show what your original `<ul>` element looks like? I believe you defined the `<ul> element and then call `.slicknav()` on it.

Comment: Edited, the HTML is now at the bottom of the post,

And yes that is precisely how it works. I have added the class of menu to my UL at its highest level, and then I call `$('.menu').slicknav();

Comment: If you add a another class to a menu item, won't SlickNav place that class on the generated item? If you add the class "xxx", you could then use '.xxx' as the selector.

Comment: I think that would only work if I added the class dynamically... 

Like perhaps If screen size is xxxx then add class. 
But the trigger event might be tricky, you could use on screen resize but wouldn't that not work if the page is opened up on a smaller device? Because technically its not resizing

Comment: It has something to do with the Listener, since the listener is applied to the element when it is called, and since SlickNav clones the menu the listeners work only on the menu if the screen is big enough for the default menu to display, they do not work if you shrink the screen for the mobile display. 

again very new lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<nav id="navMenu">
<ul class="clearfix menu">
 <li>General
    <ul class="subMenu1">
        <li class="menu_item" data-item="intro">Introduction</li>
        <li class="menu_item" data-item="requirements">What you need</li>
        <li class="menu_item" data-item="rules">House Rules</li>
...
```

And this for the JavaScript:

```
$('#navMenu, .slicknav_menu').on('click', '.menu_item', function() {
    clearBox();

    switch($(this).attr('data-item')) {
        case 'intro': {
            // Do something here.
            break;
        }
        case 'requirements': {
            // Do something here.
            break;
        }
        case 'rules': {
            // Do something here.
            break;
        }
        // More cases...
    }
});
```

It appears the cloned menu created by SlickNav is placed directly under the `<body>` element, so you cannot call `.on()` only on your `#navMenu` element. You could call it on the `body` element, but the code above calls it on both the `#navMenu` and `.slicknav_menu` elements. The `<ul>` element generated by SlickNav has the `slicknav_menu` class on it.

As written, the code above has to be called after you call `.slicknav()` since it requires the cloned menu exist when it is called. Otherwise, you would have to change to `$('body').on(...`.

As for the rest, the selector `'.menu_item'` identifies all the menu item elements, so the click-event handler will execute for all of them. But each menu item element has a different value for the `data-item` attribute. That way you can do something different for each one.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecd2vhvc/)

Comment: `$('#navMenu').on('click', '.menu_item', function() {
    clearBox();

    switch($(this).data-attr('item')) {
        case 'intro': {
            status = 1;
            statusCheck();
            break;
        }
      };
 });` 

Doesnt seem to work, It both kills the original functionality of the native menu and also seems to stop Slicknav from working entirely. 

Slicknav just doesnt fire when the screen is reduced.

Comment: Correction: 

It was me, I accidentally screwed up the call for slicknav, 
This statement has no effect on SLickNav operating ,but it still breaks the functionality of the menu items. 

It appears the clearbox is called as click on the Intro menu item removes the welcome display from the  display window, but an alert(status) to check the position of the variable isnt working. The alert call is positioned right after status=1. 


It also does not effect anything when SlickNav is visible

Comment: @LucianKain - It appears the cloned menu created by SlickNav is not placed next to the original menu, but rather is placed just under the `body` element. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nope, not working. 

More clues: I resized the screen so that it starts off in "quickNav" mode and recycled the page. 

When in this mode, clearbox no longer fires on click. 

Its as if the click handlers are not even attached to the quickNav version of the menu. Its infuriating.

Also same problem in "native" mode only clearbox() fires, status is not set to 1 and statuscheck() is not fired which kills the functionality

Comment: Edit: I didnt see that you wanted me to move the call to slicknav before the the code block. 

I've done so, it still does not work, to append the correct text to the display window, but it does  work in that it calls clearbox. 

It calls clearbox both in Mobile screen and desktop screen.

Comment: Edit: got it to work, didnt realize you also made a change to the HTML when you updated the code. I fixed it and now it works perfectly